# How to get any token contract address via network request?

Tags: web3js, erc-20, tokens, addresses

is it possible to get any token contract via network request? for now I've found this repo https://github.com/ethereum-lists/tokens/tree/master/tokens/eth but still the network request way would be much more convinient. Is there some endpoint to get the needed contract address? Thank you